# AppMaker - Google Drive Table not available

Tags: google-app-maker

Please refer to my image, "Google Drive Table" option no longer available today (suddenly) ... But i checked back my existing appmaker app, i am still able to create additional google drive table but not new app

**Missing 'Google Drive Table'**

[image: Missing 'Google Drive Table]

Answer (score 4):

For the new app it's deprecated. However you can use the one which you have created earlier for now. That also will be deprecated eventually. Refer [App Maker release notes](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes) for more information.

Comment: Thanks but ashame of Google... i dont even have chance to finish my simple app and yet they forced us to choose something which are paid tier...

Comment: this is very concerning. The main reason we signed up to app maker was the Google drive tables "just worked" and was ideal for small apps, which seems to be the focus of appmaker. The cloud SQL pricing is reported as negligible for small apps but it seems to demand a DBA to understand all the things Google drive tables hid.

Comment: @rob: That's true, we are also facing issues with Data Migration and code changes issues because we already have 2 Apps live with Drive table.